# CakePHP - Check ACL Always Returning False

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I am trying to create a view that allows the user to set ACL permissions for each group in the CakePHP application. However, when trying to perform my ACL Checks in the view, the ACL check returns false everytime.

In my controller I have the following code:

```
$this->set('acl', $this->Acl);
```

The view then users something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" <?php echo ($acl->check('Group::'.$group['Group']['id'], 'Accommodations', 'index') ? $checked : $notChecked); ?> name="<?php echo $group['Group']['name']; ?>_accommodations_index" value="1">List<br />
```

The variables $checked and $notChecked are set to the following:

```
$checked = " checked='checked' ";
$notChecked = "";
```

The goal of this essentially is to create a grid of checkboxes, where they are initially (checked if the Group has the permissions to access it, and unchecked if the group does not.

The checkboxes are printed in a table that is generated by iterating over each of the groups that exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: uses*, not users (uses something like this: )

Comment: check all permissions in the controller and pass the resulting array to the view. You're not supposed to have any logic in the view.

Comment: For corrections edit the question, if you add that as a comment someone might miss it (and also, that's why we have the edit functionality for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

```
($acl->check(array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $group['Group']['id']), 'Accommodations/index') ? $checked : $notChecked); ?>
```

I had to specify array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $group['Group']['id']) for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [url](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html#checking-permissions-the-acl-component). May be you missing somethings. It will be like as followings:

```
$acl->check(
    array(
       'Group' => array('id' => $group['Group']['id'])
    ), 
    'Accommodations', 
    'index'
);
```